# Enable direct/native running of .ps1 files -- How To

Tags: command-line, powershell, shell, file-association

#### ✅ Enable native/direct execution of .ps1 scripts - How To

**In other words: treating .ps1 files the same as .cmd or .bat files - whereby you can double-click or type their name from the console/shell and it will run the script**

**Answer below**: Through a bit of experimentation I was able to answer this question myself, so wanted to share for anyone who wanted to do this.

---

#### Linked question: Native/direct execution of .ps1 scripts - Warnings/Considerations

As part of my exploration of ***how*** to enable this, it raised the question of why this wasn't enabled by default (i.e. and so any ***warnings/reasons why you shouldn't*** do this). In an effort to best follow superuser.com guidelines, [I have created a separate question to cover this.](https://superuser.com/questions/1653312/enable-direct-native-running-of-ps1-files-warnings-considerations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary

There are two parts to enabling this (but both relatively easy)...

1️⃣ Adding ".PS1" to the `PATHEXT` environment variable

2️⃣ Specifying the host program and any behaviour options in the `Registry`

---

#### Part 1: PATHEXT

1. Edit the System Environment variables - Run (elevated) `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`, or just search for "environment" / "variables" in the start menu
2. In the second box, you will see a variable called `PATHEXT`, modify it
3. Add `;.PS1` to the end of the list (separator + .ps1 extension).

     └  NOTE: The order or the extensions is important as it is the order Windows will search / execute files (e.g. if you have `MyScript.bat`, `MyScript.cmd`, `MyScript.ps1` in the same directory and just type `MyScript` into the command shell, Windows will run the file matching the first extension it finds, searching in the order specified in PATHEXT

✅ Windows will now run a .ps1 script and (if you want) you can call a script without specifying the extension.

⚠️ **However:** Windows will use the default action/handler specified for the .ps1 filetype (in my case, this was actually opening the script in `powershell_ise.exe`), so you will likely want to adjust these as well (*see Part 2*)

---

#### Part 2: Default command (Registry)

(Before I made the above change I was already wondering: "Will use pwsh.exe or powershell.exe?" and "Will it use a profile, if so which one?" but found all of this is neatly handled by the default command and whatever you specify there is applied to a script when you run it)

**The registry code is supplied below, but first here is an explanation of the components...**

1. You can choose to run the script with `powershell.exe` (version 5, included in Windows) or `pwsh.exe` (version 7, a more modern, cross-platform version you can [install manually](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/latest))
2. By default, before running your PowerShell script, it will display the PowerShell header (copyright info, etc). Alternatively this can be disabled with `-NoLogo` (personally I prefer this, especially as it "blends" PowerShell more directly into the cmd shell, but accept that other users may prefer to keep cmd/PowerShell more distinct)
3. If you have created a profile, PowerShell will load this before running your script. Alternatively this can be disabled with `-NoProfile`

**Putting the above parts together**

```
PowerShell Script (ps1) - Default action, run.reg
-------------------------------------------------

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell]
@="pwsh_NoProfile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\pwsh_NoProfile]
@="&Run in pwsh.exe"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\pwsh_NoProfile\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe\" -NoLogo -NoProfile -File \"%1\""
```

NOTE: Normally, you would add commands to the filetype in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, however Windows seem to have done something slightly odd to the .ps1 association, so in the above .reg file I have added the command(s) directly to the extension in the SFA section as this seem to work more reliably.

---

#### That's it!

The above environment variable change and registry update will let you run any `.ps1` file by double-clicking it, or calling it's name in the console/cmd shell

(Finally, no more `pwsh.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "C:\path_to_my_powershell_scripts\MyPSScript.ps1"`, I can add "C:\path_to_my_powershell_scripts" to the `%PATH%` and just type `MyPSScript` - huzzah!! )